# Open HTML file in extension package with window.html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a browser extension and I have a credentialManager.html file that I want to open in a new window.  Currently doing this

```
     var credentialWindow = window.open("credentialManager.html",
 "Credential Manager", "width=150,height=250")
```

but it just appends credentialManager.html onto whatever website domain I'm on and opens that.  I want it to open the file with that name, which is in the extension package.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: to access a .html file in the extension package you use the following

```
var credentialWindow = window.open("ms-browser-extension://[id of extension]/[name of html file].html", "[name your popup window]", "width=[some num],height=[some num]");
```